# set RecyclerView invisible

Tags: java, android

I have a bottom navigation bar which showing the "Setting","Newsfeed" and "Profile". However, when I set to Invisible and it won't display back again. So I created an if statement to check the status of its visibility but it is not working.

```
  bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_menu);
  bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.news_icon:

                    if (mNewsFeedList.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                        mNewsFeedList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else{

                    }

                    Toast.makeText(newsfeed.this, "news", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                case R.id.profile_icon:
                    mNewsFeedList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    Toast.makeText(newsfeed.this, "profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                case R.id.setting_icon:
                    mNewsFeedList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            }

            return false;
        }
    });`
```

Another question, is it a good way to set the visibility for navigation? Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your switch statement is falling through the different cases because you are missing `break;` statements. What I think you are looking for is:

```
switch(id) {
   case id_1:
     //do some work
   break;
   case id_2:
     //do some work
   break;
   default: 
     //do other work 
}
```

[Java switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I am so dumb which miss out of the `break;`. Anyway, do you think it is a good idea to set the object invisible for navigation?

Comment: I am not sure the UI you are trying to achieve, but if this code works well for you there is no need to change it. Its okay to hide and show views when needed.